# Nodelet run via a launch file is slower than a nodelet run via a terminal

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, depth-image-proc, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run the depth_image_proc nodelet to transform a depth and colour image into a rgb pointcloud.
The nodelets are working wen i run the separately on multiple terminals, but the slowdown drastically wen i launch them in a launch file.
When launched from a terminal the **depth_image_proc/register** nodelet has frame rate of 20 fps, but wen i launch the **depth_image_proc/register** nodelet with a launch file i get around 1 frame every 5 seconds. The launch file i use is as following:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet" args="manager" output="screen"/>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="step_1" args="load depth_image_proc/register standalone_nodelet">
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/color/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="depth/camera_info" to="/camera/depth/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="depth/image_rect" to="/camera/depth/image_rect_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Does any one have a idea why the nodelet slows down when launch from a launch file and how to pevernt it?

The system i am running is a ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ROS kinetic.
Beside the nodelets i am also running the realsense2_camera demo_pointcloud.launch file to get information from the camera.

Edit 1:

I am running the following commands in two different terminal:

```
$ rosrun nodelet nodelet manager __name:=nodelet_manager
```

and

```
rosrun nodelet nodelet load depth_image_proc/register nodelet_manager __name:=step_1 rgb/camera_info:=/camera/color/camera_info depth/camera_info:=/camera/depth/camera_info depth/image_rect:=/camera/depth/image_rect_raw
```

Edit 2:

I know that the realsense2_camera uses `/camera/realsense2_camera_manager` nodelet manager.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320759/nodelet-run-via-a-launch-file-is-slower-than-a-nodelet-run-via-a-terminal/) by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-04-10**:
Can you detail exactly what you run from the terminals and also your full launch files ? One reason might be that you have different nodelets manager when using your launch files, that would basically be the same as using nodes, inducing your speed loss.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-10**:
Your edit seems to suggest the launch file and the `rosrun` line use the exact same arguments.

Can you show an `rqt_graph` screenshot both when you use `roslaunch` and one for `rosrun`?

In any case: you'll want to load your nodelet into the `/camera/realsense2_camera_manager`, otherwise it doesn't make much sense to use nodelets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The launch file i use is as following:

> ```
> <launch>
> ```

```
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet" args="manager" output="screen"/>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="step_1" args="load depth_image_proc/register standalone_nodelet">
[..]
```

this launch file hosts the nodelet `step_1` in a manager called `standalone_nodelet`.

So only *within* `standalone_nodelet` will zero-copy data exchange be used.

Any other communication with other participants in your ROS nodegraph (ie: other running nodes) will not benefit from direct zero-copy exchanges.

> Beside the nodelets i am also running the realsense2_camera demo_pointcloud.launch file to get information from the camera.

It's likely that `realsense2_camera` starts a `nodelet_manager` of its own, into which it loads a nr of nodelets.

The "nodelet run via a terminal" you mention is then likely *loaded into* the manager started by the driver. In that case you do benefit, as now zero-copy data exchange between your `depth_image_proc/register` and the realsense driver can take place.

---

Edit: it would be good if you can show how you load the nodelet "via the terminal". As that should show the difference (specifically: which nodelet manager the nodelet is loaded into).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0